# xslt 2.0 - get latest node from recursive structure

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to search for a specific node in a recursive nodes structure and read a value(s) from inside of latest one. The solution I've tried is to call template recursively with searching for a condition, then put result to a variable, then loop through a variable by for-each.
For example, my.xml:

```
<test>
    <test>
        <test>
            <test result='passed'>
                <metadata data='1'/>
            </test>
            <test result='passed'>
                <metadata data='2'/>
            </test>
            <test result='passed'>
                <metadata data='3'/>
            </test>
        </test>
    </test>
</test>
```

my.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="my_template">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>
        <xsl:if test="$node/@result and $node/@result != 'undefined'">
            <xsl:value-of select="./metadata/@data"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="$node/test">
            <xsl:call-template name="my_template">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var">
            <xsl:call-template name="my_template">
              <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="$var">
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I am getting:

```
123
```

But I expected to get only '3'

What I am doing wrong?

It seems the variable $var gets "123" as single value, if I add ',' after , I get "123,". I expected to get a set of nodes in $var to extract latest value.

Maybe there is another way to solve task? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a simple path expression using `last()` will give you the result:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(//test[@result and @result != 'undefined'])[last()]/metadata/@data"/>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBo

If you use a template and want to return a sequence of attribute nodes and also want to store them as a sequence you can access then you need to use the `as` attribute e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template name="my_template">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>
        <xsl:if test="$node/@result and $node/@result != 'undefined'">
            <xsl:sequence select="./metadata/@data"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="$node/test">
            <xsl:call-template name="my_template">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var" as="attribute()*">
            <xsl:call-template name="my_template">
              <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$var[last()]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBo/2

Comment: Great, simple path expression worked in my (a little bit more complex) case too, thanks!